# How to save an array into a variable - VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, variables

I am new to VBA so please bear with me. I am having a hard time with this code:

```
Dim arrayAC() As Variant
Dim arrayW() As Variant
Dim DD As date
Dim LrowAC As Integer
Dim LrowW As Integer
LrowAC = Worksheets("A").Columns(29).Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
LrowW = Worksheets("A").Columns(23).Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlValues, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
ReDim arrayAC(1 To LrowAC + 1)
ReDim arrayW(1 To LrowW + 1)

For i = 3 To LrowAC + 1
    arrayAC(i) = Worksheets("A").Cells(i, 29)
Next i
i = 3

For h = 3 To LrowW + 1
    arrayW(h) = Worksheets("A").Cells(h, 23)
Next h
h = 3

For i = 3 To LrowAC + 1
For h = 3 To LrowW + 1
If arrayAC(i) = arrayW(h) Then
DD = arrayAC(i)
Worksheets("A").Cells(i, "X").Value = DD
end if 
next h
next i
```

DD does not get any value! I don't know how to save the arrayAC(i) in the DD variable which is going to be printed in the excel sheet later on. Thanks,

Comment: What is `DD`, you don't declare it in the code you've provided. The assignment: `DD = arrayAC(i)` -- have you put a breakpoint on that line to see if it's being hit?

Comment: I assumed that : Dim DD As date

Comment: My mistake I didn't see that at first.  Still, did you debug?

Comment: No I am still having trouble with the code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Debug that assignment `DD = ...` and see what you can find out.  Does that line ever execute?

Comment: Yes I did. Debug shows that DD is empty! I found this useful to have: Removing the DD variable and printing the array directly might be a bad solution.                                                                Worksheets("A").Cells(h, "X").Value = arrayAC(i)                                          but this is not the real solution I want to print in the cell different variables in that cell.

Comment: That means that your conditional logic isn't sufficient or there is not any match which meet the criteria you're testing for.

Comment: No the condition is met but the value is not saved in DD

Comment: If  condition is met then DD can't possibly be empty after that line executes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116504/discussion-between-zapata-and-david-zemens).

Answer (score 0):

do this, and if you see the message box, the value should be written to column X. if you dont see the message box, then something else is wrong with your assumptions. if you see the message box more than once, you may be overwriting the cell in column x, further debugging would be necessary...

```
For i = 3 To LrowAC + 1

    For h = 3 To LrowW + 1

        If arrayAC(i) = arrayW(h) Then

            'DD = arrayAC(i)
            msgbox arrayAC(i)
            Worksheets("A").Cells(i, "X").Value = arrayAC(i)

        end if 

    Next

Next
```